How handle Notifications in selenium C#
I'm trying to automate login in a project. After trying to login, I get a browser popup:
asking me allow or block notifications.
How with the webdriver can I click Allow and proceed forward?
I've tried disabling the notifications with ChromeOptions but then the page won't load.

This question is similar to: How to click Allow on Show Notifications popup using Selenium Webdriver. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

See: How do I do X? The expectation on SO is that the user asking a question not only does research to answer their own question but also shares that research, code attempts, and results. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! See also: [ask]
